# Display all times at which a cron job runs

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, software-development, sysadmin

Ok, I can define a cron job at 17:30

```
30 17 * * * /path/to/command
```

or every 15 minutes

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/command
```

or at 5 past, 34 past and 41 past

```
5,34,41 * * * * /path/to/command
```

or at

```
*/14 3,7 */6 2-11 1,7 /path/to/command
```

which is every 14 minutes on 3 o'clock and 7 'o clock on every day that is dividable by 6, not in January and not in December **and** or **or** if it is Monday or Sunday? Or maybe it's illegal, because Sunday was `0` and not `7`?

I am looking for a software that

- takes a crontab line as input
- checks if it is valid or not
- if valid, from now on lists the next execution times
- limited to a user definable amount

E.g.

```
program -n 10 30 17 * * *
```

produces 10 lines of output (assuming today is 2015-10-22)

```
2015-10-23 17:30
2015-10-24 17:30
2015-10-25 17:30
2015-10-26 17:30
2015-10-27 17:30
2015-10-28 17:30
2015-10-29 17:30
2015-10-30 17:30
2015-10-31 17:30
2015-11-01 17:30
```

Other requirements:

- free / open source, I guess I'd even pay 20$ for it
- any OS (Debian/Ubuntu are fine, but even Windows would be ok)

Answer (score 2):

Another option for you to investigate, if you are a little in to programming, is to utilize the [java cron-utils](//github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils) library, which has this to say about it self from github:

> cron-utils aims to provide utilities that can be used across all Java cron libraries as well as to provide interoperation with time libraries such as JodaTime
>
> Current version allows to
>
> - express cron expressions as objects
> - parse expressions
> - describe and validate them
> - find last and next execution time

It has amongst others a method `nextExecutionTime()` which calculates the next time a cron job would run. This method is defined in the [model/time/ExecutionTime.java](https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils/blob/77f90d210cbc5664e2d39b1c9c353d2671ffe6eb/src/main/java/com/cronutils/model/time/ExecutionTime.java) file.

http://cron-parser.com/ is the main web page of this library, and the feature list from that page is as follows:

> ### Features
>
> - Create arbitrary cron expressions: you can define your own cron format! Supported fields are: second, minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week, year.
> - You can flag last field as optional!
> - Supports all cron special characters: * / , -
>
>   - Non-standard characters L, W, # are supported as well!
>   - Question mark (?) is currently replaced for an asterisk (*). Enhanced support will be provided in a future.
> - Print to locale specific human readable format (English, Dutch, French, Italian, Portuguese and Spanish so far...).
> - Parse and Description process are decoupled: parse once and operate with the result!
> - Validate if cron string expressions match a cron definition using CronValidator
> - Convert crons between different cron definitions: if you need to migrate expressions, CronMapper may help you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a web based [translator](https://crontranslator.appspot.com/) of the cron expressions. You can make use of javascript on this page translator.js, modify it a bit and use on your own.

Additionally, there is already similar question on Stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765180/decoding-a-cron-tab-command). I do not need to copy whole thing here as it is on the same web.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The translator already fails on `*/15 * * * *`.

Comment: The indirectly linked http://cronwtf.github.io/ does not clarify if the week days are **and** or **or**.

Comment: For http://cronwtf.github.io/, I also disagree with `* * * 2-11 *` to return March through December. http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/5/crontab/ says the numbers are 1 to 12, not 0 to 11.